# Javascript working on Android browser but not laptop browsers

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Javascript function and a Jquery function which both work on Chrome for Android. Only the Jquery function works on Chrome, Chromium, Firefox, and Safari on Mac and PC. The script is just supposed to show a "loading" div upon submission of a form.

The jquery script that works everywhere:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    });
});    // This just shows a bootstrap popover
```

The script to show the div:

```
document.getElementById('submit-upload').onclick=function() {
    document.getElementById('loading-gif').style.display = "block";
};
```

The div that should be shown:

```
<div id="loading-gif" style="display: none;">
    <div align="center">
        <%= image_tag "loading.gif" %><br/><h3>Loading</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

The form submit button:

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2">
    <%= f.submit( "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg start", id: "submit-upload") %>
</div>
```

What do I need to change to get this div to show up on PC browsers?

Comment: This should not work anywhere. When you submit a form the browser changes unloads the document and any javascript - just like when you click a link. So the handler you attach to the click event will most likely never be run. If you want to have something else happen when a form is submitted you need to [prevent the default event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Comment: If this is an ajax form that uses `remote: true` (the jquery ujs driver) you should listen for the [jquery ujs events](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) events instead to create a spinner or loading dialog.